# Node.js NPM module compatibility with popular frameworks

Tags: javascript, node.js, frameworks, sails.js

I understand that this is probably a really stupid question, but after just dipping my toes in Node.js for the first time, i'm wondering if *all* modules/packages found on NPM work with popular frameworks such as Sails.js, Meteor etc. This is obviously not the case with many PHP frameworks, for instance Laravel uses Composer,  and I was wondering if the same fragmentation applies for Node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of them do, unless stated otherwise.

It's usual in node.js to create universal libraries that can be used anywhere, not just for one particular framework.

PS: sails and meteor are way over-engineered though. I won't be surprised if they break something.

---

Node.js has a different philosophy in building modules than php. In php you pick a framework and build your app around it. With node.js it's a completely wrong approach. Since javascript is a highly dynamic language, it's really easy to build small parts and extend them.

So in node.js you build your app from scratch, and on each step you pick those small pieces of code other people wrote. This way you have full control over whatever application you're developing, and can freely change anything.

Comment: Thanks. As for which framework, I'm currently considering Sails as it is Rails-like and reasonably well supported. As you mention Sails is over-engineered, what other frameworks do you recommend?

Comment: I would recommend `express`. Note that `sails` is based on `express`, so you'll be using almost the same tools. But this way you'll have more granular control over your application.